# Does a tennis player lose the point if their racket hits the opponent due to follow through over the net?

Tags: rules, tennis

A tennis player hits the opponent with their racket due to follow through over the net when the opponent is very close to the net.
Does he/she lose the point?

Answer (score 1):

If the hit was unintentional, then that's grounds for a let (i.e. replay the point).
If the hit was done intentionally, then that's grounds for default due to the over-the-top, dangerous behavior.